# Is it possible to get a custom domain name with Powershell from an Azure web app?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have tried the following but that gets the default hostname and not the custom domain for the web app.

```
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $name
$hostName = $webApp | select-object DefaultHostName
Write-Host $hostName
```

I can't see any method to retrieve this after looking at the documentation.

By custom domain name I mean when you go to https://portal.azure.com > App Services > select an app > Overview > Browser (or URL at the top of the overview page).

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`EnabledHostNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.site.enabledhostnames?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_Models_Site_EnabledHostNames)?

Comment: You could use `$hostName = $webApp.HostNames` instead of `DefaultHostName`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes! You linked to .NET C# documentation. I can't find this for Az PowerShell 2.4.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azwebapp?view=azps-2.4.0

Comment: It's the same thing. `Get-AzWebApp` returns a `PSSite` object, and `PSSite` derives from `Site`, and `Site` has the `EnabledHostNames` property

Comment: @NancyXiong How can I get the actual string hostname with that? I saw that is an option with Set-AzWebApp but I can't seem to get anything but an empty list back with Get-AzWebApp.

Comment: Have you added the custom domain in your app service? See `Set-AzWebApp` in the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-configure-custom-domain

Comment: @NancyXiong Yes, when I navigate to it through the Azure portal it has my custom URL listed and when I click the browse button it takes me to the correct URL. I'm trying to retrieve the values from https://portal.azure.com > App Services > select an app > Overview > Browser (or URL at the top of the overview page).

Comment: Any update on your question?

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me to get the custom domains for my apps service. You could check if you have selected the correct tenant, subscription, resource group, web app when you get the web app hostname.

```
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $name
$hostName = $webApp.HostNames 
# or get all enabled hostnames using $hostName = $webApp.enabledHostNames 
Write-Host $hostName
```

[image]

Also, you should see the hostnames in the `assigned custom domains` in the **customs domains** of app service.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could filter `hostnames` to print custom domain using below

```
$URL = $webApp.hostnames | where {$_ -match 'Your Domain'}
            
if (!$URL) {$URL = $webApp.hostnames | where {$_ -match 'azure'}}
```